# Append to or create a list that is a value in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

I have a dictionary `already_eaten` whose keys are the names of my `person`s.  I would like to track the `food`s that each `person` has eaten:

```
def enter_purchase():
    food = input("What food was eaten : ")
    person = input("Who ate the food? ")
    if food in stock:
            if stock[food] > 0 :
                stock[food] -= 1
                if person in already_ate.items():# <-- 
                    already_ate[person].append(food) # <-- i want to apend food value in person key if person key exist

                else:  # <-- and if the person is not the key in dictionary then make it a new key assigning the value of food
                    already_ate[person] = food # <--
            else:
                print("{} does not ate as we are out of {}".format(person,food))
    else:
        print("{} are out of stocks".format(food))
```

Comment: you can use `get` to check if the person exists, if not it will return`None`. 
Ex : `already_ate.get("person")` will get you the person if exists or returns None

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you want to do, you want to have `already_ate` track all the foods a `person` has eaten.  It looks like your data structure is not correct for this job.

You need to change your code to handle `already_ate[person]` as a list, not a single string:

```
if person in already_ate:
    if not food in already_ate[person]:
        already_ate[person].append(food)
else:
    already_ate[person] = [food]
```

The `else` portion will both add the `person` key to your `already_ate` dictionary, and start the list with the eaten `food`.

This way you can have multiple `food`s eaten by each `person`, but not have any given `food` appear in that `person`'s list more than once.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `if person in already_ate.items():# <--` always return `False` because `already_ate.items()` returns the keys and values of `already_ate` instead of the keys.

Use `already_ate.keys()` instead. It will only return the keys.

And also, the value of the keys of `already_ate` should be a list.

```
already_ate = {'Jo' : ['Ice']} #The value of all keys should be a list
stock = {'Rice' : 9}

def enter_purchase():
food = input("What food was eaten : ")
person = input("Who ate the food? ")
if food in stock:
    if stock[food] > 0 :
        stock[food] -= 1
        if person in already_ate.keys(): #.items() to .keys()
            already_ate[person].append(food)
        else:
            already_ate[person] = food
    else:
        print("{} does not ate as we are out of {}".format(person,food))
else:
    print("{} are out of stocks".format(food))
```